# Functional Dependency Equation

Tags: database, algorithm, math, formula

```
X → Y      IF     X → Z      and     Y → Z
```

I've been trying to solve this equation using Armstrong's axioms functional dependency Transitivity rule...

With X → Z

t1[x] = t2[x] then t1[z] = t2[z]

With Y → Z

t3[y] = t4[y] then t3[z] = t4[z]

Though from here I'm lost as to how to solve the equation if it is true or false.. Reading online, but it seems to over complicate the equation.

Comment: Working from a quick skim of wikipedia, that's not true; take any relation that fulfills `X -> Z` and `Y -> Z`, but no `x` is related to any `y`. Transitivity would work if you had `Z -> Y` in the second condition, it doesn't work "in reverse". Basically, transitivity is what let's you conclude (for numbers) "if a < b and b < c, then a < c", and for functional dependency says "if X determines Y and Y determines Z, then X determines Z".

Comment: Thanks Back, was believing myself it wasn't true that's why I couldn't solve it. Just needed second opinion incase I wasn't picking it up right. Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend to check with someone who knows this stuff, like i said, I was working from a quick skim of wiki.

Answer (score 0):

The equation has **no** solution..this can't be achieved

The equation can be achieved when Z->Y

By **transitive functional dependency**,

X->Z and Z->Y
which gives

**X->Y**